# using Onselect method in js on pdf iframe

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I'm showing a pdf file in my site with iframe tag

I want to write some code that when user highlights the text of the pdf with the **mouse**, alert that text.

I don't know how can I write something like that

I think I should use the onSelect method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some [research, search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+access+text+of+pdf+in+iframe+site:stackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)